# android-sdk: android cmd not working globally

Tags: android, windows, path

I've installed the Android SDK and faced this problem: I can execute cmd `android` only inside `%PATH_TO_SDK%/tools` folder.
Here is my PATH:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\program files\graphicsmagick-1.3.21-q16;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\dvurechenskii_aa\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\dvurechenskii_aa\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 ^& MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 ^& MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;
```

and ANDROID_HOME:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\
```

what did i miss?

OS: windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have added the environment variables perfectly fine.
android/sdk in ANDROID_HOME and $ANDROID_HOME/tools and $ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools go in PATH variable.

Please note,if you have android studio installed and using windows, Android sdk is usually installed in C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk.
And you will have to use this as your ANDROID_HOME path for it to work.

After you update the path, please make sure you restart your terminal/command prompt in order to take in the updated system variables

Comment: what a mess, I have `C:\Users\my_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` what should i use and what is diffirence? i need them both?

Comment: If you are able to run the android command from inside %PATH_TO_SDK%/tools

add this path (%PATH_TO_SDK%/tools) to your PATH environment variable. It will work globally.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the problem by using these steps:

> 1. Go to: Start > Run > Type: sysdm.cpl
> 2. Once press enter, go to tabs: Advanced > Enviroment Variables...
> 3. Add new settings to System Variables
> 4. Put the new settings like this and click OK:

```
Variable name: ANDROID_HOME
Variable value: C:\Users\[PC NAME]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

> 5. Find the path variable and click edit, just add this line (do not delete the previous settings)

```
%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

There you go, you need to close your command prompt and reopen it

Was tested on WINDOWS